# Rails and Stripe. No such customer found on dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using Rails and Stripe to charge payments on our site. The live payment site is still working, but when I try to put a test payment through I get an error No such customer: cus_C0HNm69CCk3abH. This is on the master branch, and this used to work as of Thursday and no code has been changed. Here's the relevant section of the code.

```
stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  email: trip_params[:customer_email],
  metadata: {
    customer_name: trip_params[:customer_name]
  },
  source: params[:stripeToken]
)

token = Stripe::Token.create(
  card: {
    number: trip_params[:card_number],
    exp_month: trip_params[:date][:month],
    exp_year: trip_params[:date][:year],
    cvc: trip_params[:card_cvv]
  }
)

stripe_customer.sources.create(source: token.id)
```

The last line is where it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "test" Stripe keys, Stripe will look for it in their "test" database. Since your customer is a "live" customer, it wouldn't be found in the "test" database. Of course, you don't want to put a "test" payment through a "live" customer. I'd create a "test" account for that customer (different tokens, of course) and try it that way.

Comment: interesting. I just refreshed the failed payment and it worked. stripe just may have had some test db problems.